# How do i pull up results for more that one q= query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, controller

I have a search form on my site that submits the url in the form of this (those are Tag id's)

`http://localhost:3000/tags?utf8=✓&q=2%2C12%2C44`

It works for the first Tag ID but not the others

```
  def self.search(query = {})
    output = self.scoped
    output = output.where(:id => query[:q])
  end
```

TagsController:

```
  def index
    @tags = Tag.search(params)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.where` accepts an array as argument when you want a query with multiple matches. To turn your query parameter into an array you can use `split`:

```
output = output.where(:id => query[:q].split(','))
```